# Generating a Gaussian dataset in MATLAB

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab

I want to generate a bivariate Gaussian dataset. The dataset includes a total of 800 results drawn randomly from four two-dimensional Gaussian classes with means $(-3,0)'$, $(0,0)'$, $(3,0)'$, and $(6,0)'$, all with the same variance-covariance matrix

$$\Sigma = \pmatrix{0.5 & 0.05 \\ 0.05 &0.5}.$$

How can I do that in MATLAB? I'm not expert in MATLAB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Statistics Toolbox offers a function to sample from a bivariate Gaussian

```
% Specific a covariance matrix
SIGMA = [.5 .05; .05 .5 ];

% Generate four bivariate normal distributions with specified means
temp = mvnrnd([-3 0], SIGMA,800);
temp(:,3:4) = mvnrnd([-3 0],SIGMA,800);
temp(:,5:6) = mvnrnd([3 0], SIGMA, 800);
temp(:,7:8) = mvnrnd([6 0], SIGMA, 800);
```

Answer (score 5):

First, the means.

```
mu = 3*floor(rand(1,800)*4) - 3; % first dimension means
mu = [mu; zeros(1,800)]; % add second dimension
```

Given info on [multivariate normal random deviate generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution), [Cholesky factorization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/chol.html), and [MATLAB's builtin normal random number generator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/randn.html), you'll be able to understand the code below. It generates a 2-by-800 matrix, each column of which is sampled from the mixture distribution you specified in the question.

```
SIGMA = [.5 .05; .05 .5];
A = chol(SIGMA); 
randvec = mu + A'*randn(2,800);
```

I have not tested this code properly -- I don't have a local copy of MATLAB. I tried it in an [Octave web interface](http://lavica.fesb.hr/octave/octave-on-line_en.php) and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer as follow:
 (Thanks all)

```
Sigma=[0.5 0.05; 0.05 0.5];
z=mvnrnd([-3 0],Sigma,200);
x=mvnrnd([0 0],Sigma,200);
c=mvnrnd([3 0 ],Sigma,200);
v=mvnrnd([6 0 ],Sigma,200);
samples=[z; x; c; v];
plot(samples(:,1),samples(:,2),'*');
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution, Reza.  Because it is essentially identical to the one offered earlier by @Richard Willey, why don't you mark his reply as accepted?  (Upvotes and acceptance are tangible ways in which thanks can be offered on this site.)

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your idea. My reputation is not enough for up voting yet. But OK, you are right about answers, essentially these three answers have identical results.

Comment: (+1) Your reputation is now high enough to vote replies and questions up :-).

Answer (score 0):

```
% Specific a covariance matrix
SIGMA = [.5 .05; .05 .5 ];

% Generate four bivariate normal distributions with specified means
temp = mvnrnd([-3 0], SIGMA,800);
temp(:,3:4) = mvnrnd([-3 0],SIGMA,800);
temp(:,5:6) = mvnrnd([3 0], SIGMA, 800);
temp(:,7:8) = mvnrnd([6 0], SIGMA, 800);
```